# Twig: Automatically convert json string to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, twig

it's possible to automaticaly convert JSON string variable to array in Twig?

I can use for example this code:

```
{item.id}
{set array = item.parameters|json_encode()} <-- can i do this automatically for json formatted strings?
{% for parameter in array %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

But users will write own templates in admin (XML output from e-shop) so I want as few things to learn and understand the code writing. So it's possible to check all variables for JSON syntax and convert to array automaticaly?

Data will be generated from MySQL database directly to template, so there is no controller for between DB result and Twig. I also can't use JSON_TYPE in MySQL because we use old version.

Also i don't looking for something like this (or cusom filter):

```
{item.id}
{% for parameter in item.parameters|json_encode() %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

**My idea is this:**

```
{item.id}
{% for parameter in item.parameters %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

(So if there is autoescape in Twig, I am looking for "auto_json_decode" :-) )

Comment: Is it stored as json strings in the DB?

Comment: imho this is not the task of twig. You should validate and convert the data to the correct format when pulling it from the database

Comment: Yes, data in DB is stored in JSON format - the field is TEXT/VARCHAR type.
For example [{"param":"Name","value":"60"}]

Comment: And yes I also think, that is not task of twig, but for simpliest and fastest solution I am looking for this autmaticaly converting.